# CodeFile and missing using directive or assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a very old ASP Classic site I need to maintain and I'm trying to convert a feature that generated robust Excel & Word files using old ActiveX controls by using ASP.NET CodeFile files instead.

I'm more a MVC person and don't know much about web forms, but was able to build a working example of an excel report as a CodeBehind file and referencing EPPlus.  Okay so far, however when I try switching the *.aspx page to CodeFile, I get a compilation error with line 6 of my *.aspx.cs file:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OfficeOpenXml' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 4:  using System.Drawing;
Line 5:  using System.Globalization;
Line 6:  using OfficeOpenXml; <-- error here
Line 7:  using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
```

What am I'm missing about CodeFile?  Is this not possible?

<s>AFAIK the CodeFile method is what I want because it will let me seamlessly add the files to my existing ASP Classic site while going with CodeBehind will require hosting the project as a separate application.</s> See self-answer

Comment: The error is saying you don't have dll of 'OfficeOpenXml'.  You need to add reference of that in your project. Or you should check the version as well

Comment: @शेखर I have a reference to EPPlus and EPPlus.dll is in my bin folder.  EPPlus uses the namespace OfficeOpenXml.  Is it a matter of locating the dll? Where does CodeFile expect it at run-time?  Thanks

Comment: Are the version same. Have you checked the dll version and the proj file reference.

Comment: Yes both the proj file reference and the actual *.dll are version 4.1.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out my issue following @शेखर's line of questioning.  I have essentially two projects. One is a plain asp classic web site and another is an actual .NET web forms application.  My problem was the location of the bin folder with my dll.  The bin folder needs to be a the root level of my asp classic web site regardless of where my .NET files are hosted within that site.

Also I'm pretty sure I am wrong about my AFAIK in my original question. You should be good with CodeBehind provided your project's dll is also in the bin folder at the root level.  This might not make sense though if your classic site hosts unrelated "applications" separated into different folders at the root.

I'll keep this up in case another might find it useful or until it's suggested I take it down.

Thank you @शेखर for keeping me pointed in the right direction.